# How to advanced onemenu hide border line in IE

Tags: css, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 5.1 .In my application advance onemenu to show data like below image.At a time mozilla and chrome work fine but in IE 10 show border in dropdown.

```
<style>
.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-table {border-collapse:initial;}
.ui-selectonemenu-panel  .ui-selectonemenu-table td{border:none!important;}
</style>
```

I given primefaces example in second image.I need **remove the border**.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the border that you do not want to see? How is this image from IE? How does it look like in FF then (or the other way around). The client-side html is way more relevant in this case so non-PF users can help out to

Comment: @Kukeltje In second image to  I need remove the border and its support of firefox,chrome and IE 9 and above?